# Работа с 2D-графикой в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, графика, 2d

Всем привет
Каким образом можно осуществить работу с **2D** графикой в WPF?
В случае работы с 3D есть такой контролл, как Viewport3D. В нем есть тег ModelVisual3D, к которому можно привязать нужную модель, построенную во ViewModel следующим образом:
`<ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding Model}" />`
Есть ли подобный контролл для работы с 2D? Очень желательно с примерами. Если нет - буду очень благодарен за любые наводки на альтернативный способ реализации
Если быть максимально конкретным, передо мной стоит следующая задача: 
Есть список объектов, каждый из которых имеет свое графическое представление. При выборе нового объекта оно (представление) отображается в окне. Так же должна быть возможность изменять размеры выбранного объекта с перерисовкой представления в ходе программы.

Comment: Быть может `Canvas`? Вообще, если вам нужно работать с графикой, например для игр, то лучше писать под Unity.

Comment: @aepot Нет, не для игр, а просто для отображения картинки, размеры которой могут быть заданы пользователем.
Насчет Canvas тоже думаю, но пока что так и не нашел примера с реализацией через Binding

Comment: Для отображения картинки есть контрол `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с 2D графикой наиболее быстрый способ это использовать Canvas. Тут вы можете как просто добавлять примитивы как объекты (через Xaml или через ручное добавление в Children). Или так же переопределив метод OnRender можно выводить необходимые примитивы через DrawingContext.

```
 protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
 {
     dc.dc.DrawImage(myImageSource, new Rect(mySize));
     base.OnRender(dc);
 }
```

Так же можно использовать Direct2d (через WriteableBitmap/WriteableBitmapEx) или если у вас приложение на UWP то Win2D.
Так же можете воспользоваться InkCanvas (который из коробки предоставляет возможность изменять изображения своих дочерних объектов).

Ну а в целом из вашего описания задачи не совсем понятно нужно ли вообще вам использовать ту или иную отрисовку или просто воспользоваться объектом Image и просто ресайзить его (пример если разместить его в Grid и добавить GridSplitter по горизонтали и вертикали).